# return value from function VS assign to var and then return?

Tags: javascript

From time to time while writing code I'm thinking what is better ?
just return value from function or create variable for this value and then return. Is it just about taste? or there is some benefits of direct return?

```
// variant 1

function (a, b) {
  const c = a + b * 2;

  return c;
}

function (a, b) {
  return a + b * 2;
}

// variant 2

async function () {
  const {data} = await fetch(api);
  const c = {
    ...data,
    hello: "world",
  }

  return c;
}

async function () {
  const {data} = await fetch(api);

  return {
    ...data,
    hello: "world",
  };
}
```

Comment: Less code - the one and  main difference

Comment: redundant variable = redundant memory slot used. In theory, less variables - less memory. In practice, in case of function-scoped variables - micro-optimization which would make some sense only on scary loads.

Answer (score 1):

There is one plus of having more variables defined in function and more statements defined in it too. In this case you can add **more breakpoints** in function while debugging it. For example:
[image]
In this case we can check if `b` multiplication with `2` was successful or not. Otherwise if whole formula to be put as one return statement - we would not have the ability to do so. While this example is very primitive and not very reasonable for this case, however sometimes we have such huge and complex formulas that only step-by-step debugging of them may be useful to track bugs or accomplish business requirements.